# Validate hours with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have this post :

```json
{
    "store_id": "e422ecfe-4061-4cbd-adc2-364122959dac",
    "opening_hours": [
        {
            "id": "a3489e0f-aaf9-44a7-8af7-4225c25cb40e",
            "store_id": "e422ecfe-4061-4cbd-adc2-364122959dac",
            "day": 1,
            "time_slot1_closed": false,
            "time_slot1_start": "12:34",
            "time_slot1_end": "13:32",
            "time_slot2_closed": false,
            "time_slot2_start": null,
            "time_slot2_end": null,
            "comment": "Velit sint ab temporibus praesentium quo vel."
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to validate that the "time_slot1_end" is after "time_slot1_start". To do that I have this rule :

```php
return [

    'store_id' => 'required|exists:stores,id',
    'opening_hours.*.day' => 'required|between:1,7',
    'opening_hours.*.time_slot1_start' => 'nullable|date_format:H:i',
    'opening_hours.*.time_slot1_end' => 'nullable|date_format:H:i|after:time_slot1_start',
    ...
];
```

The validation fails. I have this error :

```json
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "opening_hours.0.time_slot1_end": [
            "The opening_hours.0.time_slot1_end must be a date after time slot1 start."
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of combinations, without success. What is my error ?

Comment: After validation rule probably works only with date. So you can try replacing `date_format:H:i` to just `date`

Comment: Hi Donkarnash. I had already tried that. Without success : "is not a valid date".

Comment: Then you should probably try to explore writing a custom validation rule https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures) to check whatever values you like. We can do a simple comparison of the strings, since they will always have leading zeroes on times in the morning.

```php
return [
    'store_id' => ['required', 'exists:stores,id'],
    'opening_hours.*.day' => ['required', 'between:1,7'],
    'opening_hours.*.time_slot1_start' => ['nullable', 'date_format:H:i'],
    'opening_hours.*.time_slot1_end' => [
        'nullable',
        'date_format:H:i',
        function ($k, $v, $f) {
            // get the 0 out of opening_hours.0.time_slot_1_end
            $key = explode(".", $k)[1];
            if ($v <= $this->opening_hours[$key]["time_slot1_start"])) {
                $f("Timeslot $key end must be after start time");
            }
        },
    ],
];
```

Comment: Hi miken32.I tried with your suggestion, without success. When I post **time_slot1_start: "08:00", time_slot1_end: "12:00"** , the response is : **The opening_hours.0.time_slot1_end must be greater than time slot1 start characters.** (note  the word characters in the response...). But thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi miken32, your solution works fine. Unfortunate that the native date functions does not work in this case. Merci

Answer (score 0):

It might be reading the values as a string. Try taking the values for the time slots and converting them to a date type before validating.

```
date('H:i', strtotime(time_slot1_start))
date('H:i', strtotime(time_slot1_end))
```